# Workflow foundation deserialization from business objects

Tags: .net, architecture, workflow-foundation

I'm studying Microsoft WF samples and have found that they serializing/deserializing workflows that are not finished to hold its state. I don't like it as workflow is a process and it doesn't need any additional data to continue from a different thread or code part.

Maybe I've missed something. Can you share examples of saving/loading unfinished workflows if it's possible? Maybe alternative workflow frameworks can do without serialization/deserialization. For example it could be restored from business object state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking far too small. There are many uses beyond what you can imagine right now. All workflow frameworks (unless they use some type of object db?) will serialize the workflow state so it can be continued at a later time. Microsoft WF, K2 BlackPerl and many others do this. K2 does it because you can have an item going through workflow v1 and then right in the middle someone will update the workflow to v2 but K2 is smart enough to know that is should continue processing that item under the v1 workflow.

Maybe i'm missing your question but it seems like you don't like that it serializes the workflow for storage.

Comment: Thanks Dustin. Yep, it is a little strange for me that I need to hold state in two places - first one is workflow and second one is business object. Maybe it is all right as it is different strategy. However it confuse me now.

Comment: Your business object needs it's own state. The workflow must serialize itself for long term storage along with the state of the item. So it isn't exactly duplication. But it can get confusing. WF by definition is confusing :)